# What's the story of Shravan Kumar's parents?

Tags: puranas, ramayana, karma, itihasa

As discussed in [this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/what-is-full-story-of-shravan-kumar/27267#27267), the name "*Shravana Kumara*" (श्रवणकुमार), as is genrally captured in our popular imagination, is not actually found in the *Valmiki Ramayana* based recensions. The old couple killed by *Dasharatha* are just referred to as parents of some Hermit Boy, without any mention of the name - "Shravana Kumar".

**I'd like to know the origin of the name "Shravana Kumara". Which scriptures mention it?**

Further, I remember listening in a *Srimada Bhagvatam Katha* paṇḍāl (मंडप),
 the **prologue to *Shravana Kumara's* story**,

> whence his *shudra* mother and *vaishya* father  maintained an illicit relationship with each other, and thus committing adultery with their respective spouses and also breaking the *varna-ashrama dharma*, set forth by the great *Manu*.
> And thus on the order's of the Aja, (the then King of *Ayodhaya* & *Shri Rama's* grandfather), they were adjuciated for an exile outside the country along with, sentenced to be blinded for their crimes. In the exile, the two surrendered themselves to the Lord, and were blessed with a boy. The boy being highly devoted to his parents, he got married but the wife although  propitious towards her husband, was ill-willed for her in-laws, leading *Shravana Kumara* to abandon his wife and  set forth on a pilgrimage journey with his parents. This is where the main incidents of the "popular story", involving *Dashratha* occured.

**Are there any scriptures that give some reference to the above mentioned story of  *Shravana Kumar's* parents?***

Comment: Wikipedia says "Shravan Kumar's parents, Shantanu and Gyanvanti (Malaya), were hermits. They were both blind. When they became aged, Shravan wanted him to take them to the four most sacred places of Hindu pilgrimage to purify the soul. "

Comment: <sentenced to be blinded> They aren't

Comment: Another author says "Shravan Kumar, whose life story is depicted in the Ramayana, had parents who were hermits. While both of his parents were blind, they became blind in the same moment when they failed to keep their promise to Bhagwan Shri Brahma who blessed the couple with a son but warned that, if they looked at him, they would lose their vision. Their sight is taken from them when they look at their son approximately a nonth after Sharavan’s birth."
Lets see for answers from VR!

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru, yes there are several unsourced accounts for *Shravana Kumara*. Let's see if some scripturally verifiable sources can be taken out.